# BC not handling scale = 0 correctly

Tags: bc

I defined the cbrt function to return a cube root. I need to get an integer back (even if it is close to the cube root, it will be acceptable in my case). However, when I put the scale as 0 to get an integer, I get numbers which are grossly incorrect. What is going on and how do I get an integer cube root out?

```
bc -l
define cbrt(x) { return e(l(x)/3) }
scale=1;cbrt(1000000)
99.4
scale=0;cbrt(1000000)
54
```

Comment: [The docs](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/extra/bc/bc.1.en) says: "Every expression has a scale. This is derived from the scale of original numbers, the operation performed and in many cases, the value of the variable scale. ... expr / expr ... The scale of the result is the value of the variable scale." So, one easy way to make `scale` take effect is divide by 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `scale` before calling `cbrt()` has the effect of setting the `scale` whilst `cbrt()` is evaluated. The way around it is to stash the scale as part of the function:

```
define cbrt(x) { auto z, var; z=scale; scale=5; var = e(l(x)/3); scale=z; return (var); }
```

which when called gives:

```
scale=0; cbrt(1000000)
99.99998
```

Which seems to ignore that `scale=0`. This is because it evaluates `cbrt()` which temporarily sets the `scale` to 5 and calculates your cube root (to 5 floating points), assigns that to `z` and returns *that* value (which implicitly has `scale` set to 5). You can then apply the local `scale=0` by simply dividing by 1:

```
scale=0; cbrt(100000)/1
99
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work with my original cbrt() by doing: "x=cbrt(1000000);scale=0;x/1". Which is essentially the same as what you are doing. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you have to declare the variables before using them? You could have omitted the first command and directly used the variables.

Comment: Which is far less long winded :) You can still use the `x=scale` trick if you do need to stash the existing scale I guess :)

Comment: Localization of the variables, if `z` or `var` are used outside of `cbrt()` they would get overwritten without the use of `auto`.